# Building own framework - cannot expose swift to objective-c

Tags: ios

I try to build a mixed swift and obj-c framework. I have a swift class, `ClassA` and obj-c class `ClassB`. Inside `ClassB` I have `#import "ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h"`

But the problem is that classB doesn't compile because it cannot recognise swift methods. And in the same time there is no complains to `"ProjectName/ProjectName-Swift.h"` - it imports just fine.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is your Swift class annotated with `@objc`?

Comment: Yes, I have obj annotation

Answer (score 0):

Solution - swift class and all methods must be marked as `public`